# kafka streams hopping windowed aggregation causing multiple windows at timestamp zero

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Kafka Streams DSL windowed aggregation causing multiple windows.

```
@StreamListener("input")
    public void process(KStream<String, Data> DataKStream) {

        JsonSerde<DataAggregator> DataJsonSerde =
                new JsonSerde<>(DataAggregator.class);

        DataKStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(60000).advanceBy(30000))
                .aggregate(
                        DataAggregator::new,
                        (key, Data, aggregator) -> aggregator.add(Data),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), DataJsonSerde)
                );
    }
```

**DataAggregator.java**

```
public class DataAggregator {

    private List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataAggregator add(Data data) {
        dataList.add(data.getId());
        System.out.println(dataList);
        return this;
    }

    public List<String> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

I am grouping input data based on key, then doing 1 minute window with 30 seconds hop and in aggregator I'm just collecting data and displaying.

I was expecting 1 window at the beginning and after 30 seconds another window. But the actual output is different since beginning itself 2 windows are creating.

**Expected:**

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // till 30 seconds only one window
[6] // new window after 30 seconds
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[6, 7, 8]
```

**Actual output:**

```
[1]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // duplicate window even before 30 seconds
[6] // new window after 30 seconds and 1 window from earlier will be dropped
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[6, 7]
```

Since I'm creating hoping window of 30 seconds in a 1 minute window. I believe, initially there should be only one window and after 30 seconds another window should create.

Can someone please let me know, is the actual output is expected behavior or I am missing something?

**NOTE:** I am getting input data every 4 seconds and expected/actual output is just for representation.

**From Kafka Documentation:**

> Hopping time windows are aligned to the epoch, with the lower interval
>   bound being inclusive and the upper bound being exclusive. “Aligned to
>   the epoch” means that the first window starts at timestamp zero. For
>   example, hopping windows with a size of 5000ms and an advance interval
>   (“hop”) of 3000ms have predictable window boundaries
>   [0;5000),[3000;8000),... — and not [1000;6000),[4000;9000),... or even
>   something “random” like [1452;6452),[4452;9452),....

Comment: I believe this is the default behavior coming from Kafka Streams. It's using a wall clock timestamp extractor and the windows are generated based on the wallclock time from what I understand. So in your case, two windows are created when you start the app - something like - `"start":[2019,11,20,17,39,30],"end":[2019,11,20,17,40,30]` and `"start":[2019,11,20,17,40],"end":[2019,11,20,17,41]`. Therefore, both windows will pick up the keys. But someone from the core Kafka Streams team may want to confirm this.

Comment: @sobychacko thanks for the response. Is there a way to avoid this? I don't need 2 windows at the beginning. Is it possible to use message timestamp instead of wall clock timestamp for windowing?

Comment: @PratapA.K, sobychacko's post sounds reasonable. Hopping windows are aligned to the epoch (see https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#hopping-time-windows). If you need a different behaviour, you can implement your custom windowing with `transform()`.

Comment: @BrunoCadonna I am not expecting different behavior. As per Kafka documentation at timestamp zero 1 window should create, but in my case there are 2 windows at timestamp zero

Comment: @PratapA.K Are you sure that the timestamp extracted from your first record is zero, i.e, January 1st 1970?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your windows overlap, you get multiple windows per timestamp. For your particular window configuration, you always get 2 windows (in milliseconds):

```
[0,60000)   [60000,12000) [12000,18000) ...
     [30000,90000) [90000,15000) ...
```

You cannot change this behavior, however, you could apply a `filter()` on the result (ie, `aggregate(...).filter(...)` to drop windows you are not interested in.

Furthermore, by default the record event-time is used by Kafka Streams. There is a `WallclockTimestampExtractor` but it's only used if you set it explicitly. Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#default-timestamp-extractor

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, to summarize if I have 5 mins window with 1 min hop there will be 5 windows at the beginning. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, depends what you mean by "at the beginning". If "beginning" is 0 than no, because it's corner case. If "beginning" is some timestamp in the year 2019, that yes.